# jetpack compose shadow strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to build an text field with shadow outside

This is the result I achieved so on.

[image]

But if you zoom in the picture you will see some rectangle background under white text field (please look at the corners outside of text field, there is a background)

How can I remove that background ?

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField() {

    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(15.dp)
            .shadow(5.dp)
            .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Phone number", color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 14.sp) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = Color.Transparent, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),

            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
        )
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As default the `shadow` modifier uses a `RectangleShape`, it is the reason of your issue:

[image]

Apply the **same shape** to the `shadow` and `background` modifiers:

```
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(15.dp)
        .shadow(
            elevation = 5.dp,
            shape = shape
        )
        .background(color = Color.White, shape = shape)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(50.dp),

    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
)
```

[image]